# Sliding window median in C++

Tags: c++, median, gsl, sliding-window, boost-accumulators

I need some sliding window statistics and I am considering to use `boost::accumulators` for that, however, I couldn't find the sliding window median algorithm there.

Does `boost::accumulators` provide an exact and deterministic sliding window median algorithm? And if no, is there a nice way to build one using what it provides?

Is there another robust library for sliding window statistics that would be a better choice? Maybe a C++ wrapper on [GSL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/movstat.html#)?